# Send data from TableViewCell to Controller MVC-Principle

Tags: swift, model-view-controller, swift3, view, viewcontroller

I have got a `UITableView` with `UITableViewCell` inside `UICollectionViewCell` which is created in the `ViewController`.

For both, the `UITableView` and the `UITableViewCell` I have a separate subclass file. In the `UITableViewCell`-Subclass I have a value changed delegate action linked to the `TextField` in it. Now whenever this value of the Textfield gets changed (the function is called) I need to pass the value down to my `ViewController` where it is processed.

How is that done regarding the MVC-principle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use blocks or delegates or pass the value back to the ViewController.

Inside the `UITableViewCell` subclass declare a delegate

```
protocol TableViewCellDelegate {
  func new(value: Any) // your data type here
}

class MySubclass: UITableViewCell {
  weak var delegate: TableViewCellDelegate?
}
```

Now in the `ViewController` connect to this delegate. You can pass it to the `UICollectionViewCell` subclass and from there to the `UITableViewCell`

Inside the value change delegate of the `UITextField` you call your method

```
   self.delegate?.new(value: "NewTextHere!")
```

this way the data can be passed back to the ViewController

Comment: Thank you very much for your very clear answer. I have successfully implemented this into my project.